# How to prove that a given function is a random variable

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm confused by the way to prove that a function is a random variable, specifically with the part of its measurability. The exercise is the following:

Let $(\Omega, \mathfrak{F},\mathbb{R})=([0,1], \mathfrak{B}[0,1],\lambda)$ be a probability space and $(\mathbb{R},\mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R})$ a measurable space, where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue-measure at the unity interval $[0,1]$. We define:
\begin{align}
X: (\Omega, \mathfrak{F}) &\to (\mathbb{R},\mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R})) \\
\omega &\mapsto 
    \begin{cases}
      -1 & \text{if } \omega \in [0,\frac{1}{3}]\cup [\frac{2}{3},1],\\
      2 & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases} \nonumber
\end{align}

I tried to take $B \in \mathfrak{B}(-\infty,-1],\ \ C \in \mathfrak{B}[2,\infty)$ and $A \in \mathfrak{B}(-1,2)$. Then I looked at the preimage of these sets under $X$, with the following results:

$$ X^{-1}(B)=\{ \omega :\ X(\omega)\leq-1 \}=\{\omega \in [0,\frac{1}{3}]\cup[\frac{2}{3},1]\}\in \mathfrak{B}[0,1] $$
$$ X^{-1}(C)=\{ \omega :\ X(\omega) \geq 2\}=\{\omega \in (-\infty, 0) \cup (1,\infty)\}=\{\omega \in \mathbb{R} \setminus [0,\frac{1}{3}]\cup[\frac{2}{3},1]\} \in \mathfrak{B}[0,1] $$ and
$$ X^{-1}(A)=\{ \omega :\ -1<X(\omega)<2\}=\emptyset \in \mathfrak{B}[0,1]$$

This would show that the function is measurable, right? Or, is this proof false or incomplete? I think I'm confusing something with the way to prove measurability of a function. Please forgive any thinking mistakes, I'm a beginner in measure and probability theory. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You're right, a random Variable is just a measurable function $X: (\Omega,\mathfrak{F}) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R},\mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R}))$, however I'd formulate the proof differently:

Let $A\in \mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R})$ arbitrary. Then you have to show that $X^{-1}(A)\in \mathfrak{F}$. Now divide into the 4 cases, where any combination of -1 and 2 is in A (or not). This shows measurability for every $A\in \mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R})$ and with that that $X$ is a random variable.